# Elasticseach multiple indices suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have following problem. This is actually my implementation of an "did you mean" query. If I use only one index the results fit perfectly. If I use [multiple indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) I wont get any results.

Does this query only work for single indices?

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "exmple",
    "multi_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "all",
        "size": 5,
        "gram_size": 3,
        "collate": {
          "query": {
            "source": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_all": {}
                  }
                ],
                "filter": {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "{{suggestion}}",
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields": [
                      "name",
                      "name2"
                    ],
                    "operator": "AND",
                    "lenient": true
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "params": {
            "field_name": "all"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I try this query against on single index everything works fine. If I use multiple indices the results are empty.

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "suggest": {
    "multi_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "example",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 9,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my own. I have to use [confidence parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html).

> The confidence level defines a factor applied to the input phrases
>   score which is used as a threshold for other suggest candidates. Only
>   candidates that score higher than the threshold will be included in
>   the result. For instance a confidence level of 1.0 will only return
>   suggestions that score higher than the input phrase. If set to 0.0 the
>   top N candidates are returned. The default is 1.0.